# Display the selected image on top of another div

Tags: html, css

When I select a image I can preview it. But it shows it above the upload-data div.

What I am trying to achieve it once select image the image preview div will show on top of the upload data div?

Question: Once select image how am I able to make the preview image display on top of the upload-data div?

Codepen **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/wolfgang1983/pen/bBgjyL)**

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
      <div class="well">
        <div class="upload-info">

          <div class="upload-image"></div><!-- Preview Div-->

          <div class="upload-data">
            <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <input type="file" class="file-input" />
            <p>Click any where to select file!</p>
          </div><!-- Upload image data-->

        </div><!-- Upload info-->

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.well {
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.well .file-input {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  /*This makes the button huge. If you want a bigger button, increase the font size*/
  font-size: 50px;
  /*Opacity settings for all browsers*/
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-opacity: 0;
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0)
}

.well i {
  font-size: 15rem;
  text-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #646464;
}

.well img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 280px;
}
```

jQuery

```
function readURL(input) {

  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('.upload-image img').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}

$(".file-input").change(function(){
    $('.upload-image').append('<img>');
    readURL(this);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bBgxwK

I just simply hid the `upload-data` div once the user selects a file. You can the add a cancel button and unhide the div incase the user want to select another file.

```
$(".file-input").change(function(){
    $('.upload-image').append('<img>');
    $('.upload-data').hide(); //Hide the div.
    readURL(this);
});
```

Hope it helps, don't really know if it's what you were looking for.

*EDIT*

You can unhide the div using the jquery method `.show()`.

```
$('.upload-data').show();
```